# How to output exponent value

Tags: format, exponent, fortran95

Using scientific format in output file, I get: 0.245E+02 instead of
2.45E+01.

How to output in the later format in Fortran?

```
x = 2.45
write(*,130) 'x=', x
130 format (A,E8.2)
```

---

*Update*:
*According to @Bálint Aradi's answer, I should have set `x = 24.5` in order to get `2.45E+01`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the "scientific exponential" (`ES`) format:

```
x = 2.45
write(*, "(A,ES8.2)") "X=", x
```

Comment: the answer is 2.45E+00, can you fix that to 01? :)

Comment: Not really: if you set `x` to `2.45`, then this is `2.45 x 10^0`, so in exponential format it will look either `2.45E0` or alternatively `0.245E1` (`0.245 x 10^1`). In order to get `2.45E+01` you should set `x = 24.5`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the P editing format.

```
write(*,"(A,1PE8.2)") 'X=',x
```